# Access raw video stream from Webcam - DirectShow, C#

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, webcam, directshow.net

I'm trying to build a video conference desktop software using DirectShow.Net libraries

I have been able to preview the live footage on a panel locally.
Now I need this raw data feed to go over the network.
Sorry for the noob question but I cannot figure how to get access to this feed.

Code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
private LiveJob job;
private LiveDeviceSource livedevicesource;
private bool startedrecording;

List<object> lstVideoDevices = new List<object>(10);
List<object> lstAudioDevices = new List<object>(10);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (EncoderDevice edv in EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video)) {
        lstVideoDevices.Add(edv.Name);
        label1.Text=label1.Text+" "+ edv.Name;
    }
    foreach (EncoderDevice eda in EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio))
    {
        lstVideoDevices.Add(eda.Name);
        label2.Text = label2.Text + " " + eda.Name;
    }
}

private void btnStartPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EncoderDevice video = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video).ElementAt(1);
    EncoderDevice audio = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio).ElementAt(0);

    if (video == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    job = new LiveJob();

    if (video != null && audio != null) {
        livedevicesource = job.AddDeviceSource(video, audio);
        livedevicesource.PickBestVideoFormat(new Size(640,480), 15);

        SourceProperties sourceprop = livedevicesource.SourcePropertiesSnapshot();
        pnlVideoUs.Size = new Size(sourceprop.Size.Width, sourceprop.Size.Height);

        //This line here sets panel as the preview window
        livedevicesource.PreviewWindow = new PreviewWindow(new HandleRef(pnlVideoUs, pnlVideoUs.Handle));
        job.ActivateSource(livedevicesource);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need this raw data feed

Have a look at `\Samples\Capture\DxLogo` sample coming with DirectShow.NET:

> A sample application showing *how to superimpose a logo on a data stream*. It uses 
>   a capture device for the video source, and outputs the result to a file.

Nevertheless the sample's main goal is a bit different, it features access to raw video data:

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.BufferCB( double SampleTime, IntPtr pBuffer, int BufferLen )
{
  // ...
  CopyMemory(ipDest, ipSource, (uint)m_bmdLogo.Stride);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer.
Right now I have used the PullBroadcastPublishFormat for broadcasting and WPF control(MediaElement) in Windows Forms forms for receiving this broadcast.
I'm going to try and place a server between these 2 and update my answer here if and when I succeed.
Thank you again Roman

Comment: @lmali92 did you succeed?